# How to Insert Data into Elasticsearch Using Olivere in Golang

Tags: elasticsearch, go

I need a correct example where I can insert the data into elasticsearch using olivere in golang. I have collected the data and it prints the result for each data that will be inserted. The problem is that there is no data inserted into elasticsearch.

This is the code to collect the data that will be inserted into elasticsearch.

```
indexing := company
indextype := employee 
data := lists{Id: id__,
            Article_id:      id_row,
            Category_id:     category_id,
            Datee:           date,
            Media_id:        media,
            Mention_times:   mention,
            Data_input_date: data_input_date,
            User:           user,
            name:         pc_name}

//Save to Elastic using olivere 
response := elastic.NewBulkIndexRequest().Index(indexing).Type(indextype).Id(id__).Doc(data)  
if response != nil {
        fmt.Println("Print the result", OlivereResponse)
    } 
/* log the result 
 Print the result for inserting to elastic using olivere {"index": 
{"_index":"company","_id":"2660e1","_type":"employee"}}
{"id":"26688","article_id":20,"category_id":"farming","datee":"2018-11-23","media_id":8, Mention_times: "20", "data_input_date":"2018-12-01 15:42:22","usere":"robot-kwd41","pc_name":"server"}
*/



 if OlivereResponse == nil {
       fmt.Println("Response returns null when inserting to elasticsearch using 
          olivere")
    }
```

Can anyone provide a complete example how to insert data into elasticsearch using olivere package in golang?

Thanks 
                        }

Comment: does your program - of which the above is just a fragment - compile?  What does the response say?

Comment: Yes, it is just a fragment, that is the code to collect the data. The response is,Print the result for inserting to elastic using olivere {"index":{"_index":"company","_id":"2660e1","_type":"employee"}}
{"id":"26688","article_id":20,"category_id":"farming","datee":"2018-11-23","media_id":8, Mention_times: "20", "data_input_date":"2018-12-01 15:42:22","usere":"robot-kwd41","pc_name":"server"} It does return a response. But I have no idea how to insert the data into elasticsearch using olivere. Do you have a correct example, a complete example to insert the data into elasticsearch?

Comment: ...and does that result include the data that you have just used in the call to ``NewBulkIndexRequest``?  if it *does* what makes you think it isn't working correctly?

Comment: I am not sure, do you think the code is correct?

Comment: Sorry, I can't answer if your code is working correctly as it isn't clear what it is supposed to do.  Thx

Answer (score 1):

To insert data into Elastic I am using such code:

```
func (e *Elastic) SaveDocument(index string, id string, data interface{}) error {
    _, err := e.client.Index().Index(index).Type("entity").Id(id).
        BodyJson(data).Refresh("true").Do(e.ctx)

    if err != nil {
        e.fileLogger.Log(data)
        fmt.Printf("Error save document to elastic search: %s. Save log to file\n", err.Error())
    }

    return err
}
```

Here are:

- e.client is an instance f *elastic.Client;
- e.ctx is an context.Context

Comment: Is saveDocument a function provided by elastic olivere package?

Comment: What if I want to insert many data, is it still possible to use that function?